# how to make radiobutton selected in gridview depend on value return from dataset?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataset, radiobuttonlist

i have web application in which i used gridview. In gridview i used radiobutton list this radiobutton list has two item `Yes` and `No`.i want to select one item from these two depend on value i get from dataset at the time binding.suppose my column name is `is_selected` and it returns `True` then in radiobutton list `Yes` should be checked.
This is code i have tried myself but no success,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ready To Join?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>


                   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbd_join" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" BorderColor="Transparent"
                            onselectedindexchanged="rbd_join_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                            DataValueField="is_selected">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**After Edit**

**Addition**

.cs file
on button click event this is code:

```
Dataset  ds=new Dataset();
ds=bindgrid();
if(ds.table[0].rows.count>0)
{
    grd_view.Datasource=ds.tables[0];
    grd_view.Databind();
}
public Dataset bindgrid()
{
    SqlParameter stud_ID = new SqlParameter("@student_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                stud_ID.Value = 1;
                SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand();
                cmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdSql.CommandText = "usp_select_candidate_inplacement_byAdmin";
                cmdSql.Parameters.Add(stud_ID);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataClass dl = new DataClass();
                ds = dl.dsSelect(cmdSql);
                return ds;
}
```

and this is event i added

```
protected void grd_view_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var radioList = e.Row.FindControl("rbd_join") as RadioButtonList;
                var myobject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;
                bool is_sel = bool.Parse(myobject ["is_selected"].ToString());

                radioList.SelectedValue = is_sel ? "1" : "0";

            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `RowDataBound` event:

### ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ..... OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"
```

### Code behind

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var radioList = e.Row.FindControl("rbd_join") as RadioButtonList;

        // this will be the object that you are binding to the grid
        var myObject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        bool isSelected = bool.Parse(myObject["is_selected"].ToString());

        radioList.SelectedValue = isSelected ? "1" : "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: what;'s the **Myobject** in e.Row.DataItem as MyObject;
it's giving me error on that line

Comment: MyObject represents the object you are binding it could be a DTO object or a business object. In your case, I think it would be a `DataRow` since you are using a `DataSet` I just updated the code to use a `DataRow`

Comment: thanks for reply, but i got problem how i can get exactly that value of that row from dataset for which i want to assign,can u help me on that?

Comment: This line `var myObject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;` gets the current object being bound, when you access `myObject["is_selected"]` you are accessing the **current row** to get the value of the field: `is_selected`

Comment: Jupaol,**myObject** returns null    

**var myObject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;** at this line.

Comment: Show me the code you are using to bind the `GridView`. When you debug, what's the type of `e.Row.DataItem`??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14126/discussion-between-sharad-and-jupaol)

Comment: Change `var myObject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;` to `var myObject = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;`